# tikxml and Gradle

Tags: android, xml-parsing, tikxml

I'm trying to use [tikxml](https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml) library.
I put this in build.gradle (app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
...
dependencies {
    ...    
    // tikxml
    compile "com.tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:${libs.tikxml}"
    compile "com.tickaroo.tikxml:core:${libs.tikxml}"
    apt "com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:${libs.tikxml}"
}
```

And this in my build.gradle (project) :

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

ext {
    libs = [tikxml           : '0.8.9-SNAPSHOT']
}
```

But I'm getting this error when I build the project :

> Error:Could not find com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
>       file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>       file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tickaroo/tikxml/processor/0.8.9-SNAPSHOT/processor-0.8.9-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   Required by:
>       LVS.Training.Android.Lab.SimpleEpubReader:app:unspecified

I have no folder named **m2repository** in /opt/android-sdk/extras/. I checked the URL where Gradle tried to download the library (https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tickaroo/tikxml/ and there no **tickaroo** subdir in **com** : https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/

Anybody knows if there is a problem with this library ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a SNAPSHOT release (which means it is not a stable 1.0 release),
you have to include the snapshot repository url in your build.gradle file (from where `com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.9-SNAPSHOT` etc. will be downloaded):

You have to add the url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" to your `repositories` section of your root `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
  }
}
```